# Php and XML connection(SimpleXML)

Tags: php, xml

So im trying to make a connection with steam api and my site.Steam api returns format in XML, so i have created a connection via PHP to my server using simplexml.it is something like this:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=xxxxxxx&steamids=xxx&format=xml"); 

print $xml->response->players->player->steamid;
```

And the xml file code is :

```
<response><players><player><steamid>xxxx</steamid></response></players></player>
```

So in return I get nothing while i should get this number: xxxx

Also I can get whole document with print_r($xml); but taking only some tags seems not to work
Any tips?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't include the root node `response`.  Just `$xml->players->player->steamid` (and don't post your API keys publicly here, or somebody's steamid!)

Comment: Yeah forgot about Api.Silly me!.Anyway this solved the problem.Thanks alot!